# Does a 10-bit color display necessarily support HDR?

Tags: display, hdr

Does a 10-bit panel bit depth mean that my display can output HDR?

Answer (score 0):

No, a 10-bit panel just means it can show 2^10 = 1024 colors per pixel, it says nothing about the dynamic range.

There is a discussion on this at https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/do-10-bit-and-hdr-display-mean-the-same-thing.3069479/ and more recently at https://linustechtips.com/topic/1018735-is-hdr-and-10-bit-same-thing/